# TestCafe - How to run parallel tests with remote browser?

Tags: testing, concurrency, remote-access, testcafe

I have tests written with TestCafe Studio (.testcafe) format. I want to execute my tests concurrently for the pipelines, where I'm using ** -c 2 ** with the node.js

`"test": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 testcafe -c 2 chrome --skip-js-errors --assertion-timeout 20000 --selector-timeout 20000 Tests/**/*.testcafe",`

This will open up 2 instances of chrome browser and execute my tests parallel. Which is what I want exactly.

But when I execute tests on remote browser, I'm not sure how I need to configure the concurrency so that it will run my tests parallel.

I tried below with node.js (**-c 2 remote:2**), where I expect that I can execute my tests parallel in a remote browser

`"test-ie": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 testcafe -c 2 remote:2 --skip-js-errors --assertion-timeout 60000 --selector-timeout 60000 Tests/**/*.testcafe",`

But when I execute this I just got one single connection URL, and its not starting the tests. ( But the connection details includes ***Connecting 2 remote browser(s)...*** )

```
`> NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 testcafe -c 2 remote:2 --skip-js-errors --assertion-timeout 60000 --selector-timeout 60000 Tests/**/*.testcafe

Connecting 2 remote browser(s)...
Navigate to the following URL from each remote browser.
Connect URL: http://192.168.1.1:64828/browser/connect
CONNECTED Chrome 89.0.4389.90 / macOS 10.15.7`
```

How can I get this configured to run test parallel in a remote browser?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command syntax is correct. TestCafe outputs a single URL to connect all remote instances. After you open this URL in the first browser window (and see the first `CONNECTED` message), open the second browser window and navigate to the same URL. The console will display the second `CONNECTED` message and tests will start.